# Are all symplectic $(0,1)$-matrices lower/upper block-triangular?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, positive-definite, orthogonal-matrices, symplectic-linear-algebra

**Context.** I don't expect this question is actually interesting, it just seems like a nice/fun exercise to get better acquainted with $Sp(2n)$ (and to celebrate the new year!). *In this question symplectic matrices have coefficients in $\mathbb R$ and are defined by the equation $A^TJA = J$ where $J = \begin{pmatrix}0&I_n\\-I_n&0\end{pmatrix}$. The set of real symplectic $2n\times 2n$ matrices will be denoted $Sp(2n)$.*

> **Question.** Can we classify $(0,1)$-matrices of size $2n\times 2n$ which are symplectic? (E.g. Can we understand them well enough to say how many there are?)

**Cases found by searching the web.**
It is noted already on Wikipedia that in the $2\times 2$ case the symplectic $(0,1)$-matrices are just:

$$I_2, X = \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}, \text{ and } X^T$$

As for the $4\times 4$ case, we can grab some examples from [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SymplecticGroup.html), so we at least have

$$I_4,\ \ X = \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&1\\0&1&1&0\\0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix},\ \ Y = \begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&1\\1&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$$
and their transposes.

**Progress.** I think I managed to finish the classification just modulo <s>two</s> (just one!) sub-questions I don't know the answer to. Of course, if the answers to either of the sub-questions is "No" it will massively complicate the problem.

---

**My attempts.** One question I had was:

> **Sub-Question 1.** Does either the bottom-left or top-right $n\times n$ block of a symplectic $(0,1)$-matrix have to be zero?

Anyway, it can be helpful to think of symplectic matrices in terms of the $n\times n$ blocks. The defining equation

$$\begin{pmatrix}A^T&C^T\\B^T&D^T\end{pmatrix}J\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-C^T&A^T\\-D^T&B^T\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{pmatrix} = J$$

leads to 3 conditions:

1. $A^TC = C^TA\ \ \ $ (or, $A^TC$ is symmetric)
2. $A^TD - C^TB = I\ \ \ $ (and the equivalent $B^TC - D^TA = -I$)
3. $B^TD = D^TB\ \ \ $ (or, $B^TD$ is symmetric)

---

*Continuing here with the assumption one of $B,C$ is zero.*

We have some possible solutions coming from assuming either $B = 0$ or $C=0$.

- In the case $B = C = 0$, condition 2 reads $A$ can be any invertible $(0,1)$-matrix such that $D = (A^T)^{-1}$ is *also* a $(0,1)$-matrix.

> **Sub-Question 2.** Is any invertible $(0,1)$-matrix whose inverse is also a $(0,1)$-matrix orthogonal?

[EDIT: It is true, and very easy:

Assume $AB = I$ for $(0,1)$-matrices $A,B$. Let $A(i) = \{j : a_{ij} = 1\}$ and similarly $B(k) = \{j : b_{jk} = 1\}$. Then the equation $\sum_j a_{ij}b_{jk} = \delta_{ik}$ is equivalent to $|A(i) \cap B(k)| = \delta_{ik}$.

Clearly then $|A(i)\cap A(j)| = |B(i)\cap B(j)| = \delta_{ij}$ as well. So, $A$ is the matrix for the permutation sending $i \mapsto A(i)$ and $B$ its inverse.]

Now, if $B = C = 0$, the condition is $A \in O(n)$ and $D = A$. Even if $B\neq 0$ but $C=0$ this condition is necessary, but then we also need $$B = AB^TA.$$

A couple special cases are in order:

- $B = A, C = 0$ always works. This was done in the example $Y$ above.
- If $A = I$ then $B$ can be any symmetric matrix. This was done with $X$ above, and there are two other symmetric $(0,1)$-matrices you could use in the $4\times 4$ case.

Since orthogonal $(0,1)$-matrices are just the permutation matrices, the general condition is actually easy to understand:

Suppose $A$ represents the permutation $s$. Basically, $S_n\times C_2$ is acting on the coefficients of $B = (b_{i,j})$, where the second factor is the transpose, and we are interested in counting the orbits of the subgroup generated by $(s,1)$ which has order $lcm(ord(s),2)$). The action is:
$$b_{i,j} \mapsto b_{s^{-1}(j), s(i)}$$
which either has order 1 or 2.

- It has order 1 if $s(i) = j$, so there are $n$ orbits of size 1. (Pick any $i$, then set $j=s^{-1}(i)$.)
- It has order 2 otherwise. So there are $(n^2-n)/2$ orbits of size 2.

Hence the total degrees of freedom is $(n^2+n)/2$.

---

So if I hadn't made any blunders, we have this conclusion:

> **Conclusion.** There are at least $n!(2^{(n^2 + n)/2+1} - 1)$ symplectic $(0,1)$-matrices of size $2n\times 2n$ over $\mathbb R$. Moreover, if SQ1 and SQ2 hold, this is all of them.

This does produce 3 for $n=1$ as expected, the first few values are:
$$1, 3, 30, 762, 49128, 7864200, 3019898160, 2705829391440, 5541538603950720$$
and you can compare them to the number of special linear $(0,1)$-matrices at this [mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/200678/enumeration-of-0-1-matrices-with-determinant-1).

Finally, I will mention that I was also interested in the case of symplectic $(-1,0,1)$-matrices but this seems much harder. The analog of SQ1 fails miserably, as we have the following type of example. Let $n = n_1 + n_2$ for $n_1,n_2 > 0$. Then set
$$A = D = \begin{pmatrix}I_{n_1}&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\ \ \text{ and } \ \ B = - C = \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&I_{n_2}\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not all symplectic $(0,1)$-matrices are block-triangular. The following matrix is symplectic:
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&1\\0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

A computer search found 44 counterexamples in dimension $4\times 4$, so here is another less symmetric one:
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&1\\1&1&1&0\\1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

WolframAlpha code to check it's symplectic:

[[1,1,0,1],[1,1,1,0],[1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1]]^T*[[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1],[-1,0,0,0],[0,-1,0,0]]*[[1,1,0,1],[1,1,1,0],[1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1]]